# basic iptables rules

Tags: iptables

I am trying to secure my vps server running ubuntu HardyHeron (8.04 lts). I am using iptables to block almost all incoming traffic.
I wish to allow the following:

- Web traffic (80 & 443)
- mail traffic (incoming and outgoing, 25?)
- all traffic from my home pc (I have a static ip)

Everything works great except mail. I have not yet tested incoming mail, but outgoing mail appears to be blocked when I load the chain. I have several web pages that email confirmations and those confirmations are blocked when I load the rules, but work fine when I don't have any rules.
here are the rules (output from iptables -L)

```
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp 
ACCEPT     all  --  208.69.32.132        anywhere            #fake ip, but allows all traffic from my home pc
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix `iptables denied: ' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I don't understand why the mail is blocked so I'd appreciate help on that and also what specifically to add to allow the outgoing mail.

Comment: So what's in the logs?

Comment: Just trying to figure out why things were not working - but there was too much information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your outbound mail will be failing because you are allowing outbound packets, but dropping the inbound replies. The following iptables command will add a rule to accept incoming packets that are part of connections that are already established:

```
iptables --insert INPUT 1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED --jump ACCEPT
```

You may also want to allow new inbound connections that are related to established connections (e.g. for FTP when it opens a new connection and for ICMP errors). You can do this by changing `ESTABLISHED` in the above line to `ESTABLISHED,RELATED`.

Answer (score 0):

I use a bit of a different syntax then the above. Whereas the first responder wrote:

`iptables --insert INPUT 1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED --jump ACCEPT`

I prefer:

`iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Why make this change? Adding the RELATED state allows you to, for example, receive a larger amount of errors from failed connections. Also, note how I specified the loop back interface (expressed as 'lo') in the first rule with the -i flag? You can specify NICs the sameway, like this:

`iptables --insert INPUT 2 -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

There is a lot of cool stuff in iptables; I was very grumpy to see it replaced with NFTables and have yet to invest a lot of time with NFT. Soon enough, I guess. Good luck!

Comment: But `-D` deletes rules from the firewall!

Comment: Michael; editted to correct horrific typo.